# Entity Framework Core - Complex list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
Users
Claims
UserClaims
```

I created the relationship between a user and his claims with the following code:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }        
}
```

I would like to return an array of the Claims that a user has as well. Rather than just a list of their "subscriptions" to said claims.

How can I create a list of Claims (not UserClaims) for the user object. This way I can use `User.Claims` rather than `user.UserClaims` (which I know I will need for modifying, but not for basic claim testing).

Answer (score 0):

Typing this on a tablet, so untested code, but you will need to use SelectMany for this. Something like...

```
jim.SelectMany(u => u.UserClaims.Select(uc => uc.Claim));
```

As I said, you'll need to check the exact syntax, but that should be close enough to get you going.

Comment: That will get me the results, but how do i structure the EF core class?  Whenever I try and set the property of claims = to the result, it is not included in the deliverable api call.

Comment: @TomCrosman I think you're going to need to explain what you want to do more clearly then. From your question, it sounds like you want to query the data, but from your comment here, it sounds like you're trying to do something else